# Arduino+Ethernet shield. It does not connect to a server by local name, but do connect by the IP

Tags: c++, arduino, ethernet, dhcp

I am quite new to Arduino, so probably it is a newby question.

I have a local server having local name "raspberrypi.local". It is visible ("ping raspberrypi.local" and "ssh raspberrypi.local" work) by other machines in the same local network. However, I cannot connect to it from Arduino by that name. If I change the name to IP everything works. How, if possible, to make it work also by local name?

The sketch is bellow.

```c
#include <SPI.h> 
#include <Ethernet.h>
#include <PubSubClient.h>  // MQTT 

byte mac [ ] = { 0xDE, 0xAD, 0xBE, 0xEF, 0xFE, 0xED } ;
//byte server[]     = { 192, 168, 199, 17 }; // THIS IS WORKING
char server[] = "raspberrypi.local"; // THIS IS NOT

char clientName[] = "tmp_client";
EthernetClient ethClient;
// Time to store the last MQTT access
unsigned long lastMqtt = 0;

void callback(char* topic, byte* payload, unsigned int length) {
  payload[length] = '\0';
  Serial.println(topic);
}

PubSubClient client(server, 1883, callback, ethClient);

void connect_mqtt_client() {
  if (client.connect(clientName)) {
    client.subscribe("/tmp/in/#"); // WITH IP IT IS HERE
    Serial.println("connected");
  } else {
    Serial.println("NOT(!) connected"); // WITH LOCAL NAME IT IS ALWAYS HERE
  }
}

void setup ( )  {  
  Serial.begin( 9600 );
  Ethernet.begin( mac );
  Serial.print ( "IP:" ) ;
  Serial.println ( Ethernet.localIP ( ) ) ;
  
  connect_mqtt_client();
}
 
 
void loop ( )  { 
  if (lastMqtt > millis()) {
    lastMqtt = 0;
  }
  client.loop();

  if (millis() > (lastMqtt + 10000)) {
    if( !client.connected() ) {
      connect_mqtt_client();  
    }
    if( client.connected() ) {
      client.publish("/tmp/out", "CRYA CRYA");
    }
    lastMqtt = millis();
  }

  delay(1000);
}
```

Comment: I don't think Arduino has DNS or other means of name lookup built in. If you want it, you need to do it yourself.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem.it has DNS, but `.local` is mDNS. Ethernet library doesn't handle mDNS

Comment: @Juraj, thank you very much! Though it is not a solution it is the answer I was looking for. Unfortunately I was not able to find this information before.

Comment: you could try the ArduinoMDNS library